# get last field in a JSON data array

Tags: json, postman

I have the below script that pulls back info I need based on what path I need

```
let bodyData = pm.response.json()
let country = bodyData[2].Country
console.log(country)
pm.environment.set("country", country)
```

Rather than have to say [2] I want to pull back the last one no matter how many objects are pulled through as part of the request in postman.

are you able to advise how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, it's using the `_.last` method from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#last) which is built into the app:

```
let country = _.last(bodyData).Country
```